# how does android (5) decide which wifi to connect?

Tags: android, wifi

If two WiFi-Connections are available at the same time, how does Android decide which of them to connect to? I thought it would select the strongest one but it doesn't seem to do that. It seems to retain a connection until it disappears. Isn't it possible to make Android connect to the strongest WiFi?